# Dojo script simulate click on link with specific ID

Tags: javascript, dojo

is it possible to write script in DoJo that will automatically click on link with specific id? I have link:

`<a href="overlay1" id="callMe" />`
When you click on this link some dojo library will generate overlay with specific video etc. this is not important. So I need script that will call this link when you open page. How will it looks? So:
On load page find link with id callMe, simulate click on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *dojo/dom* to select the link by it's ID and then call the links *click()* function

code example:

```
require(['dojo/dom', 'dojo/domReady!'], function(dom){
   var callMe_link = dom.byId("callMe");

   callMe_link.click();

})
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kagant15/Ls41gecu/